# BOOL with 64-bit on iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c

When I use `BOOL` for 32-bit, I get:

```
BOOL b1=8960; //b1 == NO

bool b2=8960; //b2 == true
```

But for 64-bit, I get:

```
BOOL b1=8960; //b1 == YES

bool b2=8960; //b2 == true
```

What has changed about `BOOL` from 32-bit to 64-bit?

Comment: it is better to use `TRUE` (=`YES`) or `FALSE` (=`NO`) instead of random number.

Comment: @holex clearly bad pattern, but IMHO it's worth to explain it in depth sometimes, so, people searching SO can learn more about the language. When you look around (not just SO), today's knowledge is kinda shallow and people should learn fundamentals. If they don't learn, they'll have big headache later when they'll start debugging issues like this.

Comment: Also, from a hacking / security point-of-view; weird behaviours like this often lead to exploits, if we never ask questions about them, then we can never fix them.

Answer (score 95, accepted):

@TimBodeit is right, but it doesn't explain why ...

```
BOOL b1=8960; //b1 == NO
```

... evaluates to `NO` on 32-bit iOS and why it evaluates to `YES` on 64-bit iOS. Let's start from the same beginning.

**ObjC BOOL definition**

```
#if (TARGET_OS_IPHONE && __LP64__)  ||  (__ARM_ARCH_7K__ >= 2)
#define OBJC_BOOL_IS_BOOL 1
typedef bool BOOL;
#else
#define OBJC_BOOL_IS_CHAR 1
typedef signed char BOOL; 
// BOOL is explicitly signed so @encode(BOOL) == "c" rather than "C" 
// even if -funsigned-char is used.
#endif
```

For 64-bit iOS or ARMv7k (watch) it's defined as `bool` and for the rest as `signed char`.

**ObjC BOOL YES and NO**

Read [Objective-C Literals](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/ObjectiveCLiterals.html), where you can find:

> Previously, the `BOOL` type was simply a typedef for `signed char`, and
>   `YES` and `NO` were macros that expand to `(BOOL)1` and `(BOOL)0`
>   respectively. To support `@YES` and `@NO` expressions, these macros are
>   now defined using new language keywords in `<objc/objc.h>`:

```
#if __has_feature(objc_bool)
#define YES __objc_yes
#define NO  __objc_no
#else
#define YES ((BOOL)1)
#define NO  ((BOOL)0)
#endif
```

> The compiler implicitly converts `__objc_yes` and `__objc_no` to `(BOOL)1`
>   and `(BOOL)0`. The keywords are used to disambiguate BOOL and integer
>   literals.

**bool definition**

`bool` is a macro defined in `stdbool.h` and it expands to `_Bool`, which is a boolean type introduced in C99. It can store two values, `0` or `1`. Nothing else. To be more precise, `stdbool.h` defines four macros to use:

```
/* Don't define bool, true, and false in C++, except as a GNU extension. */
#ifndef __cplusplus
#define bool _Bool
#define true 1
#define false 0
#elif defined(__GNUC__) && !defined(__STRICT_ANSI__)
/* Define _Bool, bool, false, true as a GNU extension. */
#define _Bool bool
#define bool  bool
#define false false
#define true  true
#endif

#define __bool_true_false_are_defined 1
```

**_Bool**

`_Bool` was introduced in C99 and it can hold the values `0` or `1`. What's important is:

> When a value is demoted to a `_Bool`, the result is `0` if the value
>   equals `0`, and `1` otherwise.

Now we know where this *mess* comes from and we can better understand what's going on.

**64-bit iOS || ARMv7k**

`BOOL` -> `bool` -> `_Bool` (values `0` or `1`)

Demoting `8960` to `_Bool` gives `1`, because the value doesn't equal `0`. See (**_Bool** section).

**32-bit iOS**

`BOOL` -> `signed char` (values `-128` to `127`).

If you're going to store `int` values (`-128` to `127`) as `signed char`, the value is unchanged per [C99 6.3.1.3](http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1256.pdf). Otherwise it is *implementation defined* (C99 quote):

> Otherwise, the new type is signed and the value cannot be represented
>   in it; either the result is implementation-defined or an
>   implementation-defined signal is raised.

It means that clang can decide. To make it short, with the default settings, clang wraps it around (`int` -> `signed char`):

- `-129` becomes `127`,
- `-130` becomes `126`,
- `-131` becomes `125`,
- ...

And in the opposite direction:

- `128` becomes `-128`,
- `129` becomes `-127`,
- `130` becomes `-126`,
- ...

But because `signed char` can store values in the range `-128` to `127`, it can store `0` as well. For example `256` (`int`) becomes `0` (`signed char`). And when your value `8960` is wrapped around ...

- `8960` becomes `0`,
- `8961` becomes `1`,
- `8959` becomes `-1`,
- ...

... it becomes `0` when stored in `signed char` (`8960` is a multiple of `256`, `8960 % 256 == 0`), thus it's `NO`. The same applies to `256`, `512`, ... multiples of `256`.

I strongly recommend using `YES`, `NO` with `BOOL` and not relying on fancy C features like `int` as a condition in `if`, etc. That's the reason Swift has `Bool`, `true`, and `false` and you can't use `Int` values in conditions where `Bool` is expected. Just to avoid this *mess* ...

Comment: @weijia.wang you're welcome. Just be aware, ObjC (C) is powerful language, but you can easily shoot yourself in a leg.

Answer (score 37):

For 32-bit BOOL is a `signed char`, whereas under 64-bit it is a `bool`.

---

Definition of BOOL from `objc.h`:

```
/// Type to represent a boolean value.
#if (TARGET_OS_IPHONE && __LP64__)  ||  TARGET_OS_WATCH
#define OBJC_BOOL_IS_BOOL 1
typedef bool BOOL;
#else
#define OBJC_BOOL_IS_CHAR 1
typedef signed char BOOL; 
// BOOL is explicitly signed so @encode(BOOL) == "c" rather than "C" 
// even if -funsigned-char is used.
#endif
```