# Xcode compile error on bool when device not connected

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I am trying to do a simple animation by using this snippet:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:2.0
                      delay:0.0
                    options: UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseInOut
                 animations:^{
                    [self.view setAlpha:0.7f];

                 }
                 completion:^(BOOL finished){
                     if(finished)  NSLog(@"Finished !!!!!");
                     // do any stuff here if you want
                 }];
```

But XCode is giving me an error stating:

> "Incompatibile block pointer types sending 'void(^)(uint_8t)' to
>   parameter of type 'void(^)(BOOL)'".

If I try changing the 'BOOL' to 'bool', then the code works fine when compiling on an iPad Air, but then when I disconnect the iPad and try the simulator, I get the same error, but with different types:

> "Incompatibile block pointer types sending 'void(^)(bool)' to
>   parameter of type 'void(^)(BOOL)'".

In my opinion this is weird, as it is a code snippet that seems to work for many people, and is a rather standard piece of code. What could be causing this behavior?

P.S. I also get warnings of incompatibile types in the - (void)viewWillDisappear:(bool)animated method. They also dissapear when I connect the iPad, and appear again when it is disconnected.

EDIT: ----
This code even causes errors:

```
[searchArray enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(NSString *key, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop)
     {
         address = addresses[key];
         if(address) *stop = YES;
     } ];
```

Also on the BOOL field. And the errors are the same, conflicting parameter types.

Comment: First of all, it seems like you need not just to disconnect the device but also to change the active architecture, there's a huge difference. Secondly, BOOL and bool aren't always the same at objective c as you can see at `objc.h` (/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.9.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/AppleScriptObjC.framework/Versions/A/Headers), in general you don't want to use bool instead of BOOL. Your block looks fine, it might be hard for compiler to point on the exact issue though. Make sure you use BOOL properly and rebuild the app.

Comment: I have put BOOL everywhere where it should be. Now when I use the simulator, I have a warning by "- (void) viewWillAppear: (BOOL) animated" stating that: "conflicting parameter types in implementation of 'viewWillAppear:': 'BOOL'(aka 'signed char') vs 'uint_8t'(aka 'unsigned char')". When i connect the iPad I get: "conflicting parameter types in implementation of 'viewWillAppear:': 'BOOL'(aka 'bool') vs 'uint_8t'(aka 'unsigned char')". I cannot seem to find the source of this.

Comment: Check your interfaces to not overload `viewWillAppear:` or any other standard methods. Again, most likely the fact that you connected iPad doesn't matter, it's important that you built the app for iPad - there's a difference.

Comment: @Rafal I was explaining `BOOL` vs `bool` vs `_Bool` vs `signed char` [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31270249/581190) few days ago ... You can learn here what are the differences and why to stick with `BOOL` and `YES` / `NO` ... Can you zip your project and share it somehow? This looks weird as I don't see a problem with your block, ...

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot share my project, as it is a commercial one. BUT! I have a hint, when i created a completly new project, the problem vanished. This seems that the problem is somewhere in the project settings. I do not remember changing anything that would cause such behavior, someone got any idea?

Comment: Have you tried cleaning the project including manually deleting derived data and module cache?

Comment: I did this now, sadly with no changes.

Comment: Is there a difference in project settings `Build Active Architecture Only`?

Comment: The difference is that in the main project both "debug" and "release" are written in bold letters, and in the test project only "release" is

Answer (score 2, accepted):

BOOL is a different type, depending on whether you compile for 32 bit or for 64 bit. There are different types used like Bool, bool, Boolean plus probably others - make sure that you use the same type everywhere.

Plugging in your device means that code will be compiled for your device, and not for the simulator, so this can change between 32 and 64 bit and trigger the problem.

I'd also check if there is a typedef or #define for BOOL somewhere in your code. Double-click on BOOL in your code, right-click and "Show definition".

Comment: Indeed there was a #define in one of the files. It is a shared header, but fortunately I could edit it to not produce the error. I will add the bounty when it is available.