# Swift Boolean checking

Tags: swift, boolean

So in Objective-C when using Booleans it's possible, and encouraged, to write code using a variable's non-zero value as it's boolean value, which means you can write code like this:

```
if (someBool) {
    // Stuff
}
```

Also, there are reasons why code like the following is discouraged:

```
if (someBool == YES) {
    // Might run into problems here
}
```

The reasons why checking a boolean against another boolean are better explained [here](https://www.bignerdranch.com/blog/bools-sharp-corners/), but briefly the issue is just that when you're comparing equality to `YES` or `NO` directly, you're actually comparing against `1` and `0`, respectively. Since Objective-C allows for using non-zero values as a truth value, you could end up comparing something that should be considered true against `YES` and have the expression resolve to `NO`, e.g.

```
int trueNumber = 2;
if (trueNumber == YES) {
    // Doesn't run because trueNumber != 1
}
```

Is this still an issue in Swift? Code style issues aside, if I see something like the following

```
var someBool = true
if someBool == true {
    // stuff
}
```

is that going to be an issue, or does it not really matter? Are these C-style comparisons still happening under the hood, or is there something built into the Swift BooleanType that prevents these issues?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `if <something> {}` structure in Swift requires the `<something>` to conform to the `BooleanType` protocol which is defined like this:

```
public protocol BooleanType {
    /// The value of `self`, expressed as a `Bool`.
    public var boolValue: Bool { get }
}
```

If the type doesn't conform to this protocol, a compile-time error is thrown. If you search for this protocol in the standard library you find that the only type that conforms to this protocol is `Bool` itself. `Bool` is a type that can either be `true` or `false`. Don't think of it as the number `1` or `0`, but rather as On/Off Right/Wrong.

Now this protocol can be conformed to by any nominal type you want, e.g.:

```
extension Int : BooleanType {
    public var boolValue : Bool {
        return self > 0
    }
}
```

Now if you do this (you shouldn't honestly), you're defining it by yourself what "True" and "False" means. Now you'd be able to use it like this (again, don't do this):

```
if 0 {
    ...
}
```

Comment: Okay, so the reason why the code that was a problem in Objective-C isn't an issue is simply because of the strict type-checking in Swift? It seems like in order to be used in boolean checks in Swift, a type basically has to return a strictly-typed `Bool` (as you've shown above), which avoids the issue that C and Objective-C had with the `typedef signed char`. Is it just as simple as that?

Answer (score 2):

Swift has Bool type. This is different from objective-c's BOOL which is not actual type. It is actually typedef unsigned char. When swift expects Bool you have to give it Bool otherwise it is compile error. The following code will not compile because check is not Bool

```
let check = 2
if check {
}
```

But this will work because == returns Bool

```
let check = 2
if check == 2 {
}
```

Comment: Actually `Bool` is its own type in Swift and *not* a type alias to "unsigned char" (which would be `CUnsignedChar` in Swift).

Comment: Sorry I mean Objective-C not swift

Comment: Well, it's more complicated in Objective-C, compare http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31267325/bool-with-64-bit-on-ios.

Answer (score 0):

To understand the ObjC style, you need to go back to C. In C, this statement:

```
if (something) {
    // Do something
}
```

will evaluate to `false` if `something` is null or 0. Everything else evaluate to `true`. The problem is C doesn't have a boolean type. Objective-C added `YES` and `NO` which is basically 1 and 0. So:

```
if (aBoolValue == YES) { } // Work as expected
if (anIntValue == YES) { } // False unless anIntValue == 1
```

The "discouraged" recommendation was to align with the behaviour in C. Swift has no such backward compatibility requirements. You can't write these:

```
if anIntValue {  } // Syntax error
if anObject { }    // Syntax error
```

Instead, the expression must evaluate to a boolean value:

```
if anIntValue != 0 { } // Ok
if anObject != nil { } // Ok
```