# What difference among boolean types in Objective-C?

Tags: objective-c

I tried exchange the boolean types between them, and it worked. But the CFBooleanRef presented a warning.
After all, what's the difference between them?

```
boolean_t a = true;
bool b = a;
Boolean c = b;
BOOL d = c;
CSSM_BOOL e = d;
_Bool f = e;
CGPDFBoolean g = f;
CFBooleanRef h = g;
```

Comment: Obviously `CFBooleanRef` is a reference to a boolean. Also see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31267325/bool-with-64-bit-on-ios

Comment: @Sulthan it is a reference for kCFBooleanTrue and kCFBooleanFalse. But why does it exist? What is its use?

Comment: For one thing `CFBooleanRef` is toll-free bridged to `NSNumber`. See https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/CoreFoundation/Conceptual/CFDesignConcepts/Articles/tollFreeBridgedTypes.html. It's not really a reference to raw boolean, it's a reference to a struct called `__CFBoolean`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Most of this is answered by [BOOL with 64-bit on iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31267325/bool-with-64-bit-on-ios) (and I have some temptation to dupe it to that, but there are several additional points here that aren't covered there).

90% of this question is answered by "history." Booleans in C are defined as some kind of integer. But what kind? 8 bits? Word-sized? Signed? Unsigned? They're all a little different, and numerous frameworks and systems over the years have defined their own canonical "boolean" type.

`boolean_t` comes from the Mach Kernel. `bool` is defined in `stdbool.h` (i.e. the C standard library) and refers to the `_Bool` type defined in C99.

`Boolean` is an old Carbon type. `CSSM_BOOL` is from the CDSA security frameworks. `CGPDFBoolean` is a Core Graphics type.

`BOOL` is part of Objective-C (everything else here is really C). It's a little different because its values are technically `YES` and `NO`. But it's actually the same as the others in practice.

The only really stand-out here is `CFBoolRef`, which is a completely different thing. It's a reference to an `NSNumber` object. It's not really compatible with the others.

But the underlying issue is that in the early days (first 30 years) of C, there was no standard type for "true or false" and so lots and lots of them were created, many of them ever-so-slightly different. Over time, many of them have become defined in terms of others (`BOOL` is now typically, but not always, defined as `bool` for example). But they all have their own histories because there was no standard.

[Obligatory XKCD](https://www.xkcd.com/927/)

You might be asking at this point, who cares how big a boolean values is? Doesn't `x = (int)1` and `x = (unsigned long)1` do exactly the same thing in C? Yeah; they do. It doesn't matter. Until.... imagine you pass a pointer to a boolean that is updated by reference (`[NSFileManager fileExistsAtPath:isDirectory:]` does this for example). Then the size is very, very important. I had this in one project, where someone had helpfully defined `BOOL` to be `unsigned char` when compiling with C, and `bool` when compiling with C++. So if `BOOL` was in a header, C and C++ that included that header would expect different sized results. Oh, the bugs there were glorious.... When `true == !false` fails, it is very hard to debug.

Comment: With the exception of CFBooleanRef, are the others fully compatible?

Comment: 90% compatible. See new last paragraph.

Comment: Thanks, I'll stick with Boolean or BOOL, and use the specific ones only if one day is needed.

Comment: In most modern ObjC work, I recommend C99 `bool`. You can also use `BOOL` if it makes you feel more ObjC-old-school (it's type-aliased to `bool` now). Of course if you use `BOOL`, you should also use `YES` and `NO` values to really fly the old-school flag (I'm kidding; it really, really doesn't matter; I use bool/true/false). You generally don't want `Boolean` (that's mostly for working with very old Carbon APIs). CFBooleanRef *must* be used when dealing with CoreFoundation frameworks that require it.